# Proving that a set of points $(x,y,z)$ lie on a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $C$ be the two-sided cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$

1) Let $S$ be the set of all points ($x,y,z$) in $C$ such that the normal line of $C$ at ($x,y,z$) is perpendicular to the vector $v= \hat i+\hat j+\sqrt{2}\hat k$. Prove that $S$ lies on a line $L$.

My resolution: The normal line to the surface $C$ is parallel to the gradient of $f$. Therefore a vector representation of the normal line is $\vec u=(-2x)\hat i+(-2y)\hat j+(2z)\hat k$.
We want $\vec u\cdot\vec v=0$ which leaves us with the surface equation:
$x+y-\sqrt{2}z=0$
Doesn't a surface lie on an infinite number of lines?

Comment: You want the points where this surface meets the cone (S is a set of points in C).

Comment: I see. So i need to solve the system of both of equations C and the surface that I found?

Comment: I set z=(x+y)/root(2) and plugged in z in the equation of C. I ended up with the equation y=x. Does that mean that S lies on the line y=x?

Comment: Let y = x = t then z = 2t/root(2) = root(2)t so your line is the set of vectors of the form (t, t, root(2)t) = (1, 1, root(2))t for any real number t.